# how to use for and if in guard clause?

Tags: javascript

hello i am learning javascript and stumble upon guard clause, 
i have a problem that i solved normally using nested if, but when i am trying refactor the code using the code, the output its not exactly what i want. 
so here my usual code :

```js
const  numberLetters = (str) => {
  // Code disini
  var temp = '';
  for(var x = 0; x < str.length; x++){
    if (str[x] == 1){
      temp += 'i'; 
    }
    else if(str[x] == 4){
      temp += 'a';
    }
    else if(str[x] == 3){
      temp += 'e';
    }
    else if(str[x] == 7){
      temp += 'u';
    }
    else if(str[x] == 0){
      temp += 'o';
    }
    else {
    temp += str[x];
    }
  }
  return temp;
}

// Test cases

console.log(numberLetters('s3rg31dr4g7n0v')); // sergeidragunov
console.log(numberLetters('b4d41')); // badai
```

and here using guard clause :

```js
const  numberLetters2 = (str) => {
    let  temp = '';
    for(var x = 0; x < str.length; x++){
    if (str[x] == 1) return  temp += 'i';  
    if (str[x] == 4) return  temp += 'a';
    if (str[x] == 3) return temp += 'e';
    if (str[x] == 7)  return temp += 'u';
    if (str[x] == 0) return  temp += 'o'; 
    return temp += str[x] 
    }

}
// Test cases
console.log(numberLetters2('s3rg31dr4g7n0v')); // sergeidragunov
console.log(numberLetters2('b4d41')); // badai
```

it just get the first letter, i dont know why  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets the first letter only because after the first match it returns the letter and gets out of the function. Set the values in all conditions and return in the end.
Your first way is the right way to do it

```js
const  numberLetters2 = (str) => {
    let  temp = '';
    for(var x = 0; x < str.length; x++){
    if (str[x] == 1)   temp += 'i';  
    else if (str[x] == 4)   temp += 'a';
    else if (str[x] == 3)  temp += 'e';
    else if (str[x] == 7)   temp += 'u';
    else if (str[x] == 0)   temp += 'o'; 
    else temp+=str[x]
    }
    return temp

}
// Test cases
console.log(numberLetters2('s3rg31dr4g7n0v')); // sergeidragunov
console.log(numberLetters2('b4d41')); // badai
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using an object for efficient look up of the values:

```js
const map = {"1": "i", "4" : "a", "3": "e", "7": "u", "0": "o"};
const  numberLetters = (str) => {
  var temp = '';
  for(var x = 0; x < str.length; x++){
    temp += map[str[x]] ||  str[x]; //if map look up for the number succeeds add it with the temp, else take the character.
  }
  return temp;
}

// Test cases

console.log(numberLetters('s3rg31dr4g7n0v')); // sergeidragunov
console.log(numberLetters('b4d41')); // badai
```

In your second code, you are **returning** after the **first** match is found or when **no match** is found. So always the first letter/one letter is seen in the console.

```
for(var x = 0; x < str.length; x++){
    if (str[x] == 1) return  temp += 'i';  //returned from here if the match is found, subsequent code block unreachable 
    if (str[x] == 4) return  temp += 'a';
    if (str[x] == 3) return temp += 'e';
    if (str[x] == 7)  return temp += 'u';
    if (str[x] == 0) return  temp += 'o'; 
    return temp += str[x] //this will be ignored if the any of the previous statements are satisfied.
}
```

So, in your case you cannot use `return` from the `if` blocks as you need to check for all the cases possible.

Comment: oh i see, thank you for your  reply and show me  whole new way to refactor my code ,  i cannot thank you enough :)

Comment: @Binarian_Girl Glad to help, please feel free to upvote! :)

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problem, you can use a switch case and for a neater iteration, you can also use for...of

```js
const numberLetters2 = (str) => {
    let  temp = '';
    for(let char of str){
        switch (char) {
            case '1' : 
                temp += 'i';
                break;
            case '4' : 
                temp += 'a';
                break;
            case '3' : 
                temp += 'e';
                break;
            case '7' : 
                temp += 'u';
                break;
            case '0' : 
                temp += 'o';
                break;
            default : 
                temp += char;
        }
    }
    return temp; 
}

console.log(numberLetters2('s3rg31dr4g7n0v')); // sergeidragunov
console.log(numberLetters2('b4d41')); // badai
```

Comment: thank you, it is a far lot neater than the code i write, thank you again for sharing your answer :)

Comment: Glad I could help :))